# How execute shortcode with javascript

Tags: shortcode, javascript, html

Suppose to have this shortcode:

```
[spu-close class="" text="" align=""]
```

I want to show this short code when I click on a button this is  my html:

```
 <input class="button b" onclick="openFile(link);"  type="button" value="download" />
```

and this is my js file:

```
function openFile(link){
//I want do something like this
    do_shortcode('[spu-close class="" text="" align=""]', false );
   //  

}
```

I don't know how I can do this, anyone can help me?

Comment: Not sure if this is even possibile as a shortcode is made up in PHP, and PHP is serverside. And Javascript is client side. You should be able to run this function in PHP tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to execute "ShortCode" which server side-> wordpress ->php ,by JavaScript which client side  you will need use AJAX!

you can use some thing like:

1-in your enqueued .js file :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.buttonClass').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: Param.doShortCode,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'handle_ajax_shortcode',
            },
            success: function() {
                //do something on success 
            },
            error: function() {
                //do something on error
            }
        })
    })
});
```

2- in php file :

```
//localize your script
$Param = array(

  'doShortCode'=>admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
      
);
wp_localize_script('handle_ajax_shortcode','Param', $Param);

//executes for users that are not logged in.
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_handle_ajax_shortcode', 'handle_ajax_shortcode' );
//executes for users that are logged in.
add_action( 'wp_ajax_handle_ajax_shortcode', 'handle_ajax_shortcode' );


function handle_ajax_shortcode(){
  //put whatever you want to be execute when JavaScript event is triggered
  do_shortcode( string $content, bool $ignore_html = false )
  // Don't forget to stop execution afterward.
  wp_die();

}
```

for more information you can check [Link1](https://solislab.com/blog/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/) & [Link2](http://web-profile.net/wordpress/dev/ajax-in-wordpress/) &  [Link3](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: [An anonymous user points out](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/268907) you're setting the action twice: once in the URL and once in the post body.