# How to execute WP shortcode in a javascript string ""

Tags: javascript

I would like to insert and execute some WordPress shortcode through `main.js` file, in a string "", but the problem is that it won't execute!

Here is an example of my `main.js`:

```
..
},
"March 6": {
    "title": "6 March",
    "subtitle": "Sample text",
    "content": "[sc name=\"sampleshortcode\"]"
},
..
```

So with this, I see only `[sc name="sampleshortcode"]` as executed on my WordPress page.

Looking to find the solution to show WordPress shortcode through "string". Or any other idea.

Comment: You forget that JavaScript is executed in the browser on the completed page, but WordPress' shortcodes get interpreted on the server, long before sending the result to the browser.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281671/how-execute-shortcode-with-javascript
.. OR .. 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64010/call-shortcode-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64010/call-shortcode-in-javascript) shows the process of executing a shortcode with JavaScript. You may have to do a derivative of this in order to successfully do what you are trying to do, but the methodology is inscribed within will inform your actions more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a way to get some data from database for the javascript, then you could consider using [admin-ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), [WP REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) or even [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to get and make available the data you need.